# JComponent Won't Repaint

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jtabbedpane

I have a JTabbedPane that looks like this:

```
overview= new JTabbedPane();

            JComponent accountinfo= AccountOverview(guest.toString());
            overview.addTab ("Account Overview", accountinfo);
            overview.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

            JComponent flightoption= FlightOptions();
            overview.addTab ("Book a Flight",flightoption);
            overview.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);

            JFrame tabbed= new JFrame("AIR Reservation");
            tabbed.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            tabbed.add(overview);
            tabbed.setSize(650,500);
            tabbed.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            tabbed.setVisible(true);
```

my AccountOverview method looks like this:

```
protected JComponent AccountOverview (String text)
{
    panel = new JPanel(false);
    JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);

    JButton editName= new JButton ("Edit Name");
    editName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                JFrame nameframe= new JFrame("Name Edit");
                name2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(nameframe, "Change name to: ");
                guest.setName(name2);   
            }
        });
    JButton editGender= new JButton ("Edit Gender");
    editGender.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                JFrame genderframe= new JFrame("Gender Edit");
                gen2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(genderframe, "Change gender to: ");
                guest.setGender(gen2);
            }
        });
    JButton editBirthday= new JButton ("Edit Birthday");
    editBirthday.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                JFrame birthdayframe= new JFrame("Birthdate Edit");
                birthday2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(birthdayframe, "Change birthdate to: ");
                guest.setBirthDate(birthday2);
            }
        });
    JButton editPassportNumber= new JButton ("Edit Passport Number");
    editPassportNumber.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
                JFrame passportframe= new JFrame("Passport Number Edit");
                passnum2= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(passportframe, "Change passport number to: "));
                guest.setPassportNumber(passnum2);
            }
        });

    panel.add(editName);
    panel.add(editGender);
    panel.add(editBirthday);
    panel.add(editPassportNumber);
    panel.add(destination);
    filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.add(filler);

    return panel;
}
```

I want the JLabel that is displayed on the JComponent on the tab to update the information when "Edit Name", "Edit Gender", etc. is clicked. I can't get the JPanel to repaint itself. What would the edited code look like so the displayed information would update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple. I'll demonstrate with the fisrt button.

```
final JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
```

Variable has to be declared final in order to use it inside an anonymous ActionListener.

```
JButton editName= new JButton ("Edit Name");
editName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            JFrame nameframe= new JFrame("Name Edit");
            name2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(nameframe, "Change name to: ");
            guest.setName(name2);
            filler.setText(guest.toString())
        }
    });
```

If you call setText inside the listener the information in your JLabel will update automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure out this problem for such a long time and I could only find complicated answers. Your answer was simple yet fixed my problem so quickly :)